# Working with query_posts ( arrays and query strings)

Tags: php, query-posts, array

I'm trying to use the search query along with an array of arguments to narrow down search results, but I'm failing horribly. This is what I have so far.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;          

$query_string = 's=test&category=wordpress'      

$s_array = array(
    'post_type' => 'blog',
    'caller_get_posts' => 1, 
    'paged' => $paged, 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'votes_percent',
            'value' => '50',
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'numeric',
        )
    )
);
$s_query = http_build_query($s_array);
$is_query = '&' . $s_query;
$s_streaming = $query_string . $is_query;  
query_posts($s_streaming);
```

When echoing out $s_streaming I get

```
s=test&category=wordpress&post_type=blog&caller_get_posts=1&paged=1&meta_query%5B0%5D%5Bkey%5D=votes_percent&meta_query%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=50&meta_query%5B0%5D%5Bcompare%5D=%3E&meta_query%5B0%5D%5Btype%5D=numeric
```

If I remove the meta_query keys it works, so I'm guessing that is where my problem resides.

It works fine like this

```
query_posts($s_array); //just using the array to filter

query_posts($query_string); //just using the search query
//$query_string = 's=test&category=wordpress';
```

I'm trying to build the string to query, because this fails.

```
query_posts($query_string . $s_array); //using both
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Probably because `$s_array` is an array, whereas `$query_string` is a string. I'm sure you cannot append these two. Can you edit your code to include what `$query_string` holds?

Comment: Updated. That is what I thought to, which is why I convert the $s_array to a string then tried appending it. But the meta_query keys are held in another array which is what I think the problem is.

Comment: Can you show `$query_string` value?

Comment: Sorry, Updated the question again with it's value which is 's=test&category=wordpress'

Comment: was looking for the same thing... and this function will do it! http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_args

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest not using `$query_string` to simplify things. If you're using an array, stick with the array form for the query variables:

```
global $wp;
$paged = ((int)get_query_var('paged')) ? (int)get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$s_array = array(
    'post_type' => 'blog',
    'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'votes_percent',
            'value' => '50',
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'numeric',
        )
    )
);
$new_query = array_merge( $s_array, (array)$wp->query_vars );
query_posts($new_query);
```

Comment: this works, but is ignoring the category key/value pair.

Comment: ok it must have been a flaw inside my code, because its working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to combine `$query_string` and `$s_array`, try this...

```
<?php

    //We use values of 's' and 'category' to add values to $s_array
    $query_string = 's=test&category=wordpress';

    $s_array = array(
        'post_type' => 'blog',
        'caller_get_posts' => 1, 
        'paged' => $paged, 
        'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'votes_percent',
            'value' => '50',
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'numeric',
            )
        ),
        's' => 'test',
        'category' => 'wordpress'
    );

    //Use $s_array for query_posts directly
    query_posts($s_array);
?>
```

I guess this will work...

Comment: I thought about this, but I generate the $query_string threw a search form. any way to append to an array? Also the user has the option to not include some fields. Like category sometimes won't be declared.

Comment: @TimothyJr My answer takes the variable nature of the page's query into account above and keeps everything typed as an array.